# After earning new privilege my reputations are not counted properly

Tags: bug, reputation

I observed, As I am earning reputations - It changes takes me to next level. Each level user can get few privileges.

But before achieving and after achieving next privilege reputations calculated are not correct.

Anyone observed same? How can we file bugs in our SQA site?

Comment: Not all changes are computed immediately, everywhere. However this is NOT well-documented so keeps spawning confusion, and questions like yours.

Comment: What do you mean the reputation is not calculated correctly? Do you have an example of something you see as wrong?

Comment: yes, Lets say If user earned 750 reputation - next previlege will be awarded.  In my case, consider my current rep. is 740 & I got 2 upvotes then my rep. will be 760. For that instance I am aware I got new privilege but if I log out and after login again next day I would be again to 740. Whenever i cross 750 again that will persist for long :(